# NSDate dateFromString returns nil

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsdateformatter, date-format

I have problem getting datefromstring.Result returned to me as nil.

In Debug i see below results:

```
self.searchDate=2013-10-31 13:48:16 +0000
salidaDateString=31/10/2013 14:48 08.35
prevhorasalida=08:23
```

Here below is my code.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *salidaDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.searchDate],prevHoraSalida];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *fechasalida = [dateFormatter dateFromString:salidaDateString];
```

## fechasalida is nil

How can i fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at any of the MANY related questions to yours? You need to set a format that actually matches your string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `prevhorasalida=08:23` and here you have only HH:mm not the second.

Replace your `HH:mm:ss` by `HH.mm` without the ss and using '.' instead if ':', this should work.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSString *prevHoraSalida = @"08.23";

NSString *salidaDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]],prevHoraSalida];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm"];

NSDate *fechasalida = [dateFormatter dateFromString:salidaDateString];

NSLog(@"%@", fechasalida);
```

Comment: [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
            NSString *salidaDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.searchDate],prevHoraSalida];
            
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
            
            NSDate *fechasalida = [dateFormatter dateFromString:salidaDateString];

I have changed like this ,still it is nil.?

Debug Result: self.searchDate: 2013-10-31 14:24:26 +0000
salidaDateString :31-10-2013 08.12

Comment: prevHoraSalida is coming from webservice. and it is like 08.21

Comment: Ok, just use HH.mm instead of HH:mm (replace ':' with '.'). i edited my answer.